# What Objective-C data structure does ServiceGenerator translate java.util.Map into?

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, google-cloud-endpoints

I have defined a Google Clouds Endpoints `@ApiMethod` whose argument contains a `java.util.Map`. `ServiceGenerator` has compiled this into a field of type `GTLMyServiceJsonMap`, which extends `GTLObject` without further additions.

How am I supposed to create appropriate instances of a map from `String` to `String` using this class in Objective-C? Needless to say, so far I haven't found this covered in Google's [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/Introduction).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have not found any documentation but `GTLObject.h`, but this seems to work:

```
GTLMyServiceJsonMap *jsonMap = [GTLMyServiceJsonMap object];
[jsonMap setJSONValue:valueAsString forKey:keyAsString];
```